# PageNavigationType is not matching the form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Using google app script to manipulate a google form, the PageNavigationType of a PageBreakItem is supposed to be GO_TO_PAGE. But when I call it with the code below, it's telling me that it is CONTINUE.

```
pages[15].asPageBreakItem().getPageNavigationType().toString();
```

[image: Screen Form]
I am positive that this is the right item that I'm calling, and this is the only item out of 40 or so that is incorrect. Anyt thoughts?

Comment: Please share a copy of your form and the script.